# How to send this request with bash script instead of python?

Tags: python, bash

```
import json
import requests


def query_records():
    args = {
        "table_name": "instance_group",
        "filter_list": [
            [
                {
                    "field": "account",
                    "op": "SCmp",
                    "value": "finder-others-live_group_file"
                }
            ]
        ],
        "order_field": "id",
        "start": 0,
        "length": 500,
        "order_inc": True
    }
    url = "http://misc.yard.wx.com:80/api/v1.0/query_records"
    resp = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(args))
    print resp
    print resp.content

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # url = "http://misc.yard.wx.com:80/api/v1.0/query_records"
    query_records()
```

This is a python file for sending a post request，but now I need to use bash script to send this request.
Then I used the py2curl package to convert the request into a curl command.

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Accept: */*" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Content-Length: 196" -H "User-Agent: python-requests/2.25.1" -d "{\"table_name\": \"instance_group\", \"filter_list\": [[{\"field\": \"account\", \"op\": \"SCmp\", \"value\": \"finder-others-live_group_file\"}]], \"order_field\": \"id\", \"start\": 0, "length": 500, \"order_inc\": true}" http://misc.yard.wx.com:80/api/v1.0/query_recordsop/
```

But when I execute the python file, I can receive a response, but there is no response when I execute this curl command. Why is it? And what should I do?

Comment: This url is for the intranet.

Comment: Can you not just do `python your_script.py` in bash?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following parameters, from the curl documentation,

https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--trace

`-S, --show-error`

You can also use the following parameter,

`-v, --verbose`

Makes curl verbose during the operation. Useful for debugging and seeing what's going on "under the hood".

For even more output, you can use

`--trace <file>`

Enables a full trace dump of all incoming and outgoing data, including descriptive information, to the given output file. Use "-" as filename to have the output sent to stdout. Use "%" as filename to have the output sent to stderr.